# How to do a case-insensitive string comparison?

Tags: c, string, string-comparison, case-insensitive, strcmp

I want to do a case-insensitive string comparison. What would be the easiest way to accomplish that? I have the below code which performs a case-sensitive operation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *str1 = "String";
    char *str2 = "STRING";

    if (strncmp(str1, str2, 100) != 0)
    {
        printf("=(");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: convert [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) first then compare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can afford deviating a little from strict `C` standard, you can make use of [`strcasecmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp).
 It is a POSIX API.

Otherwise, you always have the option to convert the strings to a certain case (UPPER or lower) and then perform the normal comparison using [`strcmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp).

Comment: you mean `strncasecmp`?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Upto you, you (almost) always have the length delimited version. Anyway, the man page I liked has both the version covered I guess. :-)

Comment: You meant *linked*..

Comment: @WedaPashi hah, my bad. yes right you are. (sorry, edit period is over) :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use strcmpi() function.

```
if(strcmpi(str1,str2)!=0)
```

only for Windows systems.

Comment: Pardon me, but isn't it windows specific?

Comment: man `strcmpi` --> no manual entry for strcmpi

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Need to check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759942(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Also, you could just mention to include `Shlwapi.h`